# Вывод текста glfw

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opengl, glfw

Можно ли как то вывести текст с помочью методов openGL? Вариант с TextOut мне бы подошёл но он не может перемещаться вместе с координатами объекта есть какие ни будь другие варианты? (без дополнительных библиотек)

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void Button(string text,double size, float posX, float posY);
GLuint LoadTexture(const char* filename);
GLuint textureid;

int main()
{
    GLFWwindow* window;
    std::cout << "Started";
    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(500, 500, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    LoadTexture("test.bmp");

    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        /* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        Button("Test",0, 0.2, 0.2);

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
GLuint LoadTexture(const char* filename)
{
    GLuint texture;
    int width, height;
    unsigned char* data;

    FILE* file;
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
    file = fopen(filename, "rb");

    if (file == NULL) return 0;
    width = 1024;
    height = 512;
    data = (unsigned char*)malloc(width * height * 3);
    //int size = fseek(file,);
    fread(data, width * height * 3, 1, file);
    fclose(file);

    for (int i = 0; i < width * height; ++i)
    {
        int index = i * 3;
        unsigned char B, R;
        B = data[index];
        R = data[index + 2];

        data[index] = R;
        data[index + 2] = B;
    }

    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);

    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    free(data);
    textureid = texture;
}

void Button(string text,double size, float posX, float posY) {
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureid);
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(-1 + posX, -1 + posY, -1);
    glScalef(0.2, 0.2, 0);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
    glVertex2f(0, 0);
    glVertex2f(1 + size, 0);
    glVertex2f(1 + size, 0.5 + size);
    glVertex2f(0, 0.5 + size);
    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код взял с форума , полностью рабочий.

Обычный текст(2d):

```
GLuint nFontList;
 
// Создание
nFontList = glGenLists(256);
wglUseFontBitmaps(hDC, 0, 256, nFontList); //(hDC - Devece Context с выбранным шрифтом)
 
// Использование
glRasterPos2i(0, 200);
glListBase(nFontList);
glCallLists (13, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, "Hello, world!");
```

3d текст:

```
GLuint nFontList;
GLYPHMETRICSFLOAT agmf[256];
 
// Создание
nFontList = glGenLists(256);
wglUseFontOutlines(hDC, 0, 256, nFontList, 0.0f, 0.5f, WGL_FONT_POLYGONS, agmf);
 
// Использование
glPushMatrix();
glListBase(nFontList);
glCallLists (6, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, "OpenGL");    
glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: Есть одна маленькая проблемка с этим кодом. Ну совсем махонькая - функция glRasterPos2i и другие - это функция с OpenGl 1, а они сейчас малось задеприкейчены.

Comment: да, но более простых вариантов решения проблемы нету(

Comment: может, но смысла особого нет. Сейчас практически никто не использует старый OpenGl.

Answer (score 1):

В целом, отрисовка текста - это просто создания большой картинки с набора маленьких массивов для каждой буквы. Потом это превращается в текстуру и отрисовывается два треугольника, которые составляет прямоугольник. Все просто. Есть готовый пример - http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-11-2d-text/

Если шрифт не подходит, всегда можно поискать в интернете картинки или нарисовать свою.

Но если ручками не хочется, но "лишних библиотек" также, то можно взять библиотеку [stb](https://github.com/nothings/stb), а там нужно взять [один нужный хедер](https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_truetype.h). Там же на гитхабе есть минимальный пример - https://github.com/justinmeiners/stb-truetype-example/blob/master/main.c

по такой [ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=stbtt_GetCodepointHMetrics) можно найти много вопросов и примеров на SO.

Если все таки захочется библиотечно - [вот пример](https://habr.com/ru/post/473990/)

Comment: Я правда не увидел как загружается изображение tga в этом примере : http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-11-2d-text/

Comment: а никто не заставляет делать именно tga, можно и bmp. А его загрузка (если условится на формат) очень и очень проста.

Comment: загрузить то я загрузил но она не отображается)

Comment: У Вашего кода есть одна большая проблема - его не видел никто кроме Вас

Comment: Редактировал, смотрите что тут не так? А можно ли использовать ttf формат?

Comment: glBegin ? opengl первой версии?

Comment: Этого я не знаю но использую GLFW 3 API

Comment: а вообще хоть что то рисуется?

Comment: ну рисуется только прямоугольник на нём текстуры нету